# OCR-Can't Read Numbers From Image Even With Greyscaling

Tags: java, user-interface, numbers, ocr, grayscale

I have been working on a bingo GUI in java that basically keeps track of all your bingo boards for you. It is going great so far but currently I or the user would have to manually enter all the numbers on a bingo card into a text document. Then the program handles it from there by reading the text document, putting the numbers in, figuring out placement of the board and size on screen, analyzing's input from user to make sure no mistakes has been made, resets boards when requested by user, and I even implemented a change command. However, I want the user to simply be able to take a picture of each bingo board and put the pictures into the file destination and that is it. In order to do this, I knew I would need some sort of image reader. I learned that this is called OCR. I found a you tube video and got the OCR to work on some images. However, I quickly learned that it only read the red characters, not the black bingo numbers. So stack over flow thread I read upon said to convert to grey scale. I look up on google on how to do that and I successfully was able to convert the image to grey scale using java. Then when I put that new image into the OCR, it still doesn't work, in fact it is worse as it doesn't read anything from that specific file. So anyways, here is my images, one being before grey scale and one being my converted grey scale image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpzND.jpg

I know stack overflow doesn't like it when people upload all of the code, so I will try to post only the relevant OCR code. If you want to see the greyscale code or my actual bingo program code, let me know. However, I have not transferred in my OCR or greyscale code into my actual bingo program code yet as I am in the testing phase still. Here is the OCR code:

Main Class

```
package com.chillyfacts.com;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class my_main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String input_file="E:\\testfiles\\bcard.png";
 String output_file="E:\\testfiles\\outputOCR";
 String tesseract_install_path="E:\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract";
 String[] command =
    {
        "cmd",
    };
    Process p;
 try {
 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
        PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
        stdin.println("\""+tesseract_install_path+"\" \""+input_file+"\" \""+output_file+"\" -l eng");
        stdin.close();
        p.waitFor();
        //System.out.println();
        //System.out.println();
        //System.out.println();
        //System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Read_File.read_a_file(output_file+".txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is SyncPipe class:

```
package com.chillyfacts.com;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
class SyncPipe implements Runnable
{
    public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
        istrm_=istrm;
        ostrm_=ostrm;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            final byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
            for (int length=0;(length=istrm_.read(buffer))!=-1;)
            {
                ostrm_.write(buffer,0,length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private final OutputStream ostrm_;
    private final InputStream istrm_;
}
```

Here is the Read File Class:

```
package com.chillyfacts.com;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
public class Read_File {
    public static String read_a_file(String file_name) {
        BufferedReader br = null; 
        String read_string="";
        try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_name));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        read_string=read_string+sCurrentLine;
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        return read_string;
    }
}
```

I am new to OCR so please go easy on me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it looks like all your java code does is call Tesseract against your input file and push the results to your output file via shelling the cmd prompt.  I don't think anything you've posted here can be changed to improve the way Tesseract works unless there are command line arguments you can supply to it in your command statement that would affect the way it handles colors.

Comment: It might help to give the tesseract-ocr help page a look.  Seems there are a few options: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc

Comment: This is only the ocr code, like I said, so you probably seen the images with one regular and the other bing greyscale. I thought tesseract would be able to read the numbers from the image. But it doesn't, so I guess I am asking how to get this to read correctly. Maybe you need to look at some more code?

Comment: I seen the wiki you gave but I am not sure on what exactly you're saying. The tesseract does read from some images that I gave it, just not the one I want, so how can I make it read from the one I want? I initially thought it was because of color, thus why I converted to greyscale, but now I am not for sure.

Comment: Well it could be a number of issues, like the angle the number is at, the font size, etc.  You might try feeding different dpi values, like --dpi 300 or --dpi 1200 to see if it help the ocr engine find the numbers.  From the examples they posted, it should have no trouble spotting numbers.

Comment: Okay so I am new to OCR. It looks like dpi stands for dots per inch. So my first question is how do I change that with my code, I just got the code from a you tube video. I understand making the dpi value smaller would have it analyze more, thus better.

Comment: I looked at my code and tried seeing what methods are available and the only thing that looked like it might do something with dpi is doing istrm_.mark(int m) but it doesn't say anything in the comments about dpi. It says something about "to allow that many bytes to be read before the mark position gets invalidated. "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199925/discussion-between-j-e-carter-ii-and-bob-g).

Comment: Seems like I might be way over my head after talking with Carter through the chat. I tried removing the lines as discussed at the end and it got some of the numbers correct but in completely random orders as well, not consistent. So maybe I need a program that removes lines from images and for that I would need to know neural networks, which I don't...who knew ocr could become so complicated. I will go talk to some of my professors at my college to see if they can help me out as I clearly need a lot of help. Should I just close this thread?